# How can I limit the power from a battery for my RPi3?

Tags: pi-3, power-supply

I am taking an old HP G62-407DX apart, and I have replaced the motherboard with a raspberry pi. With some help on Superuser, I figured out what the display used. Now, I would like to know how to limit the power output of my battery. I am trying to use the battery that the computer normally uses, but on the battery, it says "10.8V  4200 mAh." I really don't want to burn out my pi, so any answers on how to do this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: voltage regulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this situation you are going to need an adapter that converts 10.8v down to the 5v needed by the Raspberry Pi. Typically you would use what is called a [Buck Converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) for this.  These are readily available in online stores such as Amazon, ebay, etc.

Do a search for terms such as "[12v to 5v dc-dc buck converter with usb output](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&q=12v%20to%205v%20dc-dc%20buck%20converter%20with%20usb%20output)" to find one.

**Note:** For your input (10.8v) you will specifically want one that accepts input voltages less than 12v.

Good luck! Let us know what you find.

Comment: My RPi has been running for the last couple of years like this. I have a 12V battery connected to a battery charger that is designed to be permanently connected and then I have a pair of those low cost (only a few GBP each) buck-boost converters with an input range of 7 to 18 Volts DC - one provides 12V at up to 3A (IIRC) for things that need it (my electric front door lock and a wireless RC receiver) and the other a 5V 3A supply to my RPi (via an RPi specific UPS).

Comment: @MrChips Thanks for the great answer. I actually took apart an outdated car charger, following my friends instructions, and one of the boards inside (I don't remember the exact name) is functioning as a voltage regulator. I will definitely look into your solution though if this one breaks.

Comment: @JaredGizersky Awesome!  Glad to be of assistance.  Merry Christmas!